# backbone.js jquery ui resizable slow

Tags: jquery-ui, backbone.js, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm making a puzzle using backbone.js as my framework.

I've got it set up like this:

- The `PuzzleBoard` has a model and a view.
- The `PuzzleBoard` model contains a collection of 200 `Piece`s.
- Each `Piece` has a model and a view.
- Each `PieceView` is draggable and resizable (my puzzle is non conventional and let's people resize pieces).
- Each `PieceView` has a set of functions.
- There are also some UI menus that each have a model and a view.

I'm using [jquery UI resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/), and the problem is that **the resizable is really slow**. Any ideas? Anything wrong on the conceptual level with my setup? I'm wondering whether it's because I've got too many instantiated pieceViews in memory? Does the fact that each instantiated `pieceView` has a copy of a set of common `PieceView` functions cause any problems?

Comment: Are the resizable events going through a Backbone view? All the delegation involved might be slowing things down quite a bit.

Comment: Yes in the `PieceView` `initialize()` I'm doing `$el.resizable({/*ops*/});`

Comment: But how are the resizable events being handled?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what it means "how the events are being handled?". In each .resizable() I have a `start: function(e){/*some logic*/}` and a `stop` one as well...

Comment: Can you share the contents of any of the callback functions that you pass to .resizeable(/*opts*/)? That may provide a clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that some other code was binded to window resize, and resizing divs triggered that code.

Comment: Huh, same thing was happening to me, you saved me a lot of debug time. Thanks

Comment: This is how I solved it:  $(window).bind("resize", function(ev) {
  if(ev.target===window) {
   //do your thing
  }
 });